# replace number after word

Tags: lua

I have a big file with the word **engineHealth":1000.0** I want to change the number after **engineHealth":**

Comment: This does not seem like a programming question, just use find and replace. if you're using VS Code's like you say in you title, the find and replace tool excepts regex which makes the task trivial.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html
In your case `string.gsub()` would work.